# Not able to add background image to bootstrap Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a background image on the header of the modal and so I thought if I would do the following:

```
.modal-header{
background-image: url('../images/extended_top_provider.gif');
}
```

The header would display the image but it does. Instead it does the following:

[image]

I also tried to add icons for the different browsers but it doesnt display the image either.

Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

I am able to add the image, not the right one, something wrong with the path of the image, but the images below are not aligning correctly, I do not know why.

```js
$(function(){
  $('##myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
.client_logos {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="ie-only" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
         <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header" style="background: url('http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg');">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h2 class="modal-header">Outdated Browser Detected</h2><p>Our website has detected that you are using an outdated browser. Using your current browser will prevent you from accesing featuers on your website. An upgrade is not required, but is strongly recommend to improve your browsing experince on our website.<br /><br />
                            <b>Use the links below to download a new browser or upgrade your existing browser.</b></p>                       
                        </div><!---Modal-Header Div--->
                        <div class="modal-body client_logos">
                         <p>  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e3/Firefox-logo.svg/120px-Firefox-logo.svg.png" alt="image" />
                             <img class="img-responsive" src="https://productforums.google.com/forum/image/GDF/15104268797498972201/8f39d8ec-5483-4e30-977d-817c8fd1c110" /> </p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Body Div--->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                         <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Footer Div--->
                    </div><!---Modal-Content Div--->
                </div><!---Custom Height Div--->
            </div><!---Modal Fade in Div--->
        </div><!---Start of Modal Div--->     
  <!--End of Modal container-->
```

Comment: Oh,probably because modal-header doesn't contain anything in it, so it doesn't have size ?

Comment: True but I was able to grab an image and put in a styling on the same div the modal-header is located and it would appear fine

Comment: now you write how you want to position your image

Comment: it doesnt work. The only way is to add the images is to use background-image and style in the header modal. I also not able to align the image

Comment: can you post a picture of what you want to see

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of one very simple reason, `background-image` property does not take any width and height, so you may specify your width and height to `.modal-header` like this :

```
.modal-header{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-image: url('../images/extended_top_provider.gif');
}
```

Try this, and spot the difference, if you want you could simply add an `<img>` tag inside your `.modal-header` but note that `background-image` doesn't stop page rendering, while `img` tag does :)

Comment: If I would go with the img tag, what would I do?

Comment: well you must make example code and than I'll edit some little things for you :) I don't want to do all your job, please make a fiddle with that modal